# Limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(−1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Limit: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(−1)^n$$
I know the limit is $\cos{1}$, but I am not sure how to get to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how $\cos -1$ and $\cos 1$ are related?

Comment: my answer  : $\cos (-1)^n=\cos(1)^n=\cos (1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\cos (x)$ is an even function, meaning that $\cos (-x) = \cos (x)$. What can you conclude about the sequence now?

Comment: ahh, yeah, makes sense, so to answer with $\cos(-1)$  would be correct as well?

Comment: @Mykybo Yes. Your sequence is constant.

Answer (score 1):

my answer:  cosine is even function, so

$\cos (-1)^n=\cos(1)^n=\cos (1)$